# How to get Select clause's body with JSQLParser

Tags: java, sql, parsing

I'm using JsqlParser `0.8.0`.

I have the following string:

```
String sql = "SELECT table alias FROM table;";

CCJSqlParserManager pm = new CCJSqlParserManager();

Select s = (Select) pm.parse(new StringReader(sql));

System.out.println(s.getSelectBody());
```

I expected the `table AS alias` to be printed, but the whole `sql`-query was printed instead. How can I make printing only the `SelectBody`.

Comment: the selectbody will only tell you what type of query it is (eg instanceof update, select , delete, insert) you didn't actually run the query so your alias hasn't been added to the table name, check this out for how it's used http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SelectBody** is of type **PlainSelect**. This is not equivalent to the **SelectItems** which you want to get. This is an example for getting these items:

```
String sqlStr = "SELECT mytable alias FROM mytable";
Select select = (Select)CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sqlStr);
System.out.println(select.getSelectBody());

PlainSelect pl = (PlainSelect)select.getSelectBody();
for (SelectItem item : pl.getSelectItems()) {
    System.out.println(item.toString());
}
```

By the way this example is using *JSqlParser V0.9.3* but the relevant parts of getting the **SelectItems** are identical in *V0.8.0*.

You should not using keywords as column or tablenames. This could confuse in many ways the parsing process. However, more and more keywords are allowed in recent versions of *JSqlParser*.