# JSQLParser gel all select items from query and subquery

Tags: java, sql, jsqlparser

I want to get all the select items from query and subquery

as per this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30505741/8249665 I can get select items from the main query.

For subquery  like this- `"SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE SALARY > 4500)`", I'll have to navigate to `selectbody -> where -> rightItemList -> again selectbody -> finally items.`

Also, there can be more nested selects. How do I achieve it for both with subquery/subqueries and without subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a simple extension of the link you mentioned.

To traverse the parse tree **JSqlParser** provides the **visitor pattern**. Here I reuse the **TablesNamesFinder**, which uses a for your purposes complete implementation of visiting all nodes. Now it is of **no importance** how deeply your sqls are nested. For each call of the overwritten method you get the main SQL or sub selects of your SQL.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JSQLParserException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE SALARY > 4500)";

    Select select = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);

    TablesNamesFinder tablesNamesFinder = new TablesNamesFinder() {
        @Override
        public void visit(PlainSelect plainSelect) {
            System.out.println("plainselect -> " + plainSelect.toString());
            for (SelectItem item : plainSelect.getSelectItems()) {
                System.out.println(item.toString());
            }
            super.visit(plainSelect);
        }
    };

    tablesNamesFinder.getTableList(select);
}
```